# Spring Security create session basing on JWT token on new page

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, plotly, plotly.js

I have `Spring Boot` application with `REST endpoints` secured with `Spring Security` and `JWT token`.

I'm using `SmartGWT` app as client but now I would like to use `plotly.js` to create interactive plots on website.

There are no bindings for GWT so I thought to create single page (with plot and some form to select conditions of data to show) in my `Spring` application and redirect user from `GWT` app to the new page with plot. But in client I have authentication with `JWT token` so I would have to create session basing on `JWT token`.

Is it even possible in `Spring`? If so - how to do that?

Second idea was to pass token to new page and refresh it in `javascript` code but my `GWT` app is also refreshing it so there would be conflict...

Or maybe there is better solution to my problem? I would prefer not to create bindings for `plotly` to `GWT`...

Here's my Spring Security config:

```
private static final String FORM_BASED_LOGIN_ENTRY_POINT = "/api/auth/login";
private static final String TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT = "/api/**";
private static final String TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT_ADMIN = "/api/admin/**";
private static final String TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT_ADMIN_SERVICE = "/api/admin/service/**";
private static final String TOKEN_REFRESH_ENTRY_POINT = "/api/auth/token";

[...]

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors()
            .and()

            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(this.authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()

            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
            .and()

            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(FORM_BASED_LOGIN_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(TOKEN_REFRESH_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT_ADMIN_SERVICE).hasRole(Role.SERVICE.name())
            .antMatchers(TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT_ADMIN).hasAnyRole(Role.ADMIN.name(), Role.SERVICE.name())
            .antMatchers(TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT).authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(buildAjaxLoginProcessingFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(buildJwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Comment: @dur I have added configuration to my post. But I don't think you understood my problem, I want to create session for user so he could have access to authenticated area by passing his previously retreived JWT token.

Comment: If you use a HTTPS session, you don't need to pass the JWT token, your are already logged in. Your configuration seems okay, so it should work without JWT.

Comment: @dur but I'm logging to server in using API REST endpoint, I'm not showing page created in Spring, just GWT client "page"

Comment: You are using `SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS`, so Spring should create an HTTP session. However, if Spring doesn't do it, you could always do it yourself in your JWT filter.